# Flutter initState() not retrieving data immediately, need to do hot reload to view it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
class _SelectMedChallengeState extends State<SelectMedChallenge> {

List<String> categoryList;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  setState(() {
    categoryList = DatabaseService().getCategoryList();
  });
  print(categoryList);
}

createAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
  return AlertDialog(
    content: Center (
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'CATEGORY',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
          ButtonTheme (
            minWidth: 288.0,
            height: 109.0,
            buttonColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 199, 227),
            child: RaisedButton (
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'BEGINNER',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 62, 62),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MedChallenge()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ButtonTheme (
            minWidth: 288.0,
            height: 109.0,
            buttonColor: Color.fromRGBO(248, 227, 160, 1.0),
            child: RaisedButton (
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'INTERMEDIATE',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 62, 62),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MedChallenge()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ButtonTheme (
            minWidth: 288.0,
            height: 109.0,
            buttonColor: Color.fromRGBO(234, 135, 137, 1.0),
            child: RaisedButton (
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'ADVANCED',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 62, 62),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MedChallenge()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
});
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(248, 227, 160, 1.0),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(77, 72, 91, 1.0), //#4D485B
      ),
      title: Text(
        'CATEGORIES',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(77, 72, 91, 1.0), //#4D485B
          fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),

      ),
      centerTitle: true,

      actions: <Widget>[],

    ),

    body: Center(
      child: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          thickness: 2.0,
        ),
        itemCount: categoryList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              createAlertDialog(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${categoryList[index]}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'MuseoSans',
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),

 );
}
}
```

In my iniitState() I'm trying to initialize my categoryList to data that I'm querying from the cloud firestore by calling DatabaseService().getCategoryList() which is a function I have written to query the the database. Then I try to use the categoryList in the body of my scaffold in the ListView. When I go to that screen in my app, the body is empty and in the console it prints an empty list. The only time the data actually shows up is if I do hot reload when I'm in the category screen. I tried doing hot restart and running the app again and the body is still empty until I do a hot reload after I navigate to that screen in my app. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `DatabaseService().getCategoryList()` is a Future or Stream, then you're not waiting for a response, you're trying to get it immediately over your initState.

Move your method inside a function using the `async` keyword or simply add:

`.then((result) => // your login)` at the end of your Future.

Once you're sure you are getting the result for your asynchronous call, you can call `setState` to update the list and display the results.

Example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  _fetchList();
}

_fetchList() async {
  DatabaseService().getCategoryList().then((result) {
    setState(() => categoryList = result);
  });
}
```

Others uses to fetch a list could be:

```
setState(() {
    categoryList.addAll(result);
});
// Another one
for (var item in items) {
  setState(() {
    categoryList.add(item);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is how my getCategoryList() function looks, do I need to make it asynchronous? If I do though, then how can I call it in initState() because I can't make initState() asynchronous 
`List<String>  getCategoryList() {

    List<String> categoryList =[];

    categoryCollection.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot catDocs) {

      for(int i = 0; i < catDocs.documents.length; i++) {

        categoryList.add(catDocs.documents[i].data['category']);

      }

    });

    return categoryList;

  }`

Comment: add you DatabaseService().getCategoryList() method in a function like I suggested in my answer. Let me update that to show you an example.

Comment: Check my example now

Comment: When I try to add .then((result) => I get an error that 'then isn't defined for the class List"

Comment: then your getCategoryList() method should return the Future.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to mark my answer as correct to help others with a similar doubt :) Glad to help!